# How do I match records from two different datasets using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have got two dataframes of different shapes  like:

Df1:

| Index | State | city | xyz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AL | Ala | . |
| 1 | CA | . | . |
| 2 | AK | . | . |
| 3 | AR | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |

Df2:

| Index | State | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AL | 121 | 4456 |
| 1 | AK | 42 | 1266 |
| 2 | AZ | 1421 | -426 |
| 3 | AR | 121 | 456 |
| . | . | . | . |

I want to compare the State column in both the datasets and then for each state put the Lat and Long values for that state in the df1 frame. Something like this (using python, pandas and jupyter notebook):

| Index | State | city | xyz | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AL | Ala | . | 121 | 4456 |
| 1 | CA | . | . | 198 | 4541 |
| 2 | AK | . | . | 42 | 1266 |
| 3 | AR | . | . | 121 | 456 |
| . | . | . | . | ... | .... |

I have no Idea how to do this.
Thank you for reading this question, I am still a beginner, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='State')
```

Comment: please do not answer obvious duplicates, it sets bad precedents